# How can I make running individual tests faster with Jest in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, jestjs, webstorm

WebStorm has a feature that lets you right-click on an `it` and run that test. I use it often in my workflow.

When I choose 'mocha' it runs like this and is basically instantaneous. Jest takes over 20 seconds presumably because it's scanning all my files to find a pattern match.

Is there any way to make this faster? There is no question that running all of our tests is faster when run through jest... but it's terrible for running individual tests like when you're debugging.

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/blake/Documents/git/handle/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --ui bdd --reporter /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js /Users/blake/Documents/git/handle/lib/test/helpers/state-abbr-helper.spec.js --grep "^#state-abbr-helper fake test$"
this test did nothing at all...
```

```
/usr/local/bin/node --require /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-stdin-fix.js /Users/blake/Documents/git/handle/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --colors --reporters /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-reporter.js --verbose "--testNamePattern=^#state-abbr-helper fake test$" --runTestsByPath /Users/blake/Documents/git/handle/lib/test/helpers/state-abbr-helper.spec.js
  console.log lib/test/helpers/state-abbr-helper.spec.js:7
    this test did nothing at all...
```

[image: sample jest workflow]

Answer (score 0):

Check your jest.config.js to see if it's doing anything heavy to start at the test such as something like:
`setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/_ui/test/setupTest.js'],`

Answer (score 0):

In my case was the coverage slowing it down. I solved it by adding
`--collectCoverage=false`
to the run configuration, overriding the file configuration.